# composer remove (uninstall) all installed packages (composer install rollback)

Tags: php, composer-php, uninstallation

I have a project with the `composer.lock` file.
I installed packages with the command:

```
composer install
```

Now I would like to roll back that `composer install` command to the state as it was before running it.

How to remove all packages without affecting `composer.lock` file?
Is there any single `composer` command to do that?

I tried:

```
composer remove *
```

but I got:

> [UnexpectedValueException]
> "LICENSE" is not a valid alias.

I tried:

```
composer remove */*
```

But then I get bunch of print like:

> bin/console is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
> Package "bin/console" listed for update is not locked.

Why `composer remove *` did not work at all? AFAIK the package name as `VendorName/PackageName` is a common convention for Packagist but not a must (if you use private repos) so how one would be able to remove all packages named `IdontHaveAnySlash` etc. at once?

I may use someting similar to:

```
for package in $(composer show | awk '{print $1}'); do composer remove --no-interaction --dev --no-install "$package"; done
```

But that is not a simple and single `composer` command.
Also composer often complains about a package being a part (dependency) of another one so `composer` does not uninstall it.

> Removal failed, doctrine/annotations is still present, it may be required by another package. See `composer why doctrine/annotations`.

As my intention is to rollback to the state that did not have any package installed but only files: `composer.lock` and potentially `composer.json` I really don't care about any dependencies, packages versions, downloading repositories' urls etc.

I just want to have a project without any installed dependencies as it was before.

Is there any single `composer` command to do that?

My:

```
composer --version
```

is:

> version 2.2.7 2022-02-25 11:12:27

Comment: All dependencies are installed in `vendor` directory - you can just remove it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get the last state before running `composer install`, or remove all packages? Do you want to remove them forever? Then you **need** to modify your `composer.lock`, such that a following `composer install` won't install them again

Comment: Not all dependencies use `vendor/` - especially TYPO3 or Drupal modules that get installed into different folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rm -rf vendor
```

In any case, `install` should not make any **changes** to a lockfile, so there shouldn't be anything to "revert" from an `install` but deleting the installed files.

If the lockfile does not originally exist, then it will be created.

If some other plugin (e.g Symfony Flex) makes changes to your existing files during the process, you'd better have the project on top of a version control system, in which case reverting is managed by VCS, not of composer.

> As my intention is to rollback to the state that did not have any package installed but only files: composer.lock and potentially composer.json

For you to be able to run  `composer install` at all, you need at the very least `composer.json` to exist. `install` reads from the lockfile (`composer.lock`), but requires the JSON configuration file to exist as well. If the lockfile does not exist, `update` will be run instead and the lockfile will be created.

> I tried `composer remove`

`remove` is the opposite from `require`. It removes packages from `composer.json`, as `require` adds them. Not the opposite of `install`. There is no opposite of install, as it does not make much conceptual sense. If one needs to delete the installed project... one can always do so.

Comment: Once again thank you for the detailed answer. I created a simple test to verify it. It's appreciated that you mentioned this issue: `If some other plugin (e.g Symfony Flex) makes changes to your existing files during the process ...`. Would composer be able to list such packages that modified other files and revert that by `composer remove`? It seems to me that although removing `vendor` dir in most cases would work as a rollback the true and reliable rollback could be achieved only by using VCS as you mentioned.

Comment: Indeed, generally the only truly reliable way is having the project under VCS. Flex will attempt to "remove" its recipes on uninstallation, but I'm not 100% sure how well it works. Other plugins could work differently. One could also run with `--no-plugins`, but having everything under VCS makes most of these concerns go away.